# How to disable the Copy/Hide feature in UIImagePickerController when long pressing a image ...?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller, ios8.3

[image]- Actually am using UIImagePickerController for my usecase,and if i long press any picture ,it shows Copy/Hide option (as shown in the sample image)

```
   - I dont want the Copy/Hide feature.
```

Guide me with some suggestions if u too have encountered :)...

Thanks in advance...iOS Geeks...PLZ refer my code snippet below....

```
 ![@IBAction func allPhotosItemButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        let popOver: UIPopoverController = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: imagePicker)
        popOver.presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem(sender, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
    }![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Even am experiencing the same problem.....if someone had come across this problem and found the solution do share it...

Comment: When i click hide its showiing error :: [UIAlertController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its orientation issues. `UIImagePickerController`
 wont support landscape mode..

Try this code
*source ::  https://gist.github.com/mkeremkeskin/0ed9fc4a2c0e4942e451*

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    if ( orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait
        | orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    UIDevice* device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    if (device.orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to implement your own custom image pickercause I dont think what you are asking for can be done